# Tool to adjust CSS position absolute values

Tags: css

Is there a tool to aid positioning of `position: absolute` elements? Possibly a JS bookmarklet. It should do this and nothing else; it shouldn't touch the HTML.

Storage could be achieved by outputting the generated CSS in a textarea.

Also it would be nice if it had features like "snap to edges" and "alignment guides", to easily align elements to each other.

**Edit:** It should aid positioning with drag-n-drop.

Comment: Have a look to jQuery-UI "draggable", "dropable" and "position". This page might help you: http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

Comment: @sinsedrix I was asking if there is an existing tool. jQ UI is a lib with which I could build such a tool

Comment: Sorry I don't know such a tool, this is why I didn't answer, just commented. But I think it won't be so difficult to build one. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, these bookmarklets can help you align elements on the page.

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Rule

http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Unit

Comment: +1 Thank you, best answer so far, don't know who down voted. It doesn't do exactly what I wanted (drag-drop elements), but it's close. Will accept until a better one comes up.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing to note on that site is http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/grid . 

BTW, if you ever find it or something very related, please let me know. I am a bit of a collector of cool bookmarklets. In fact I noted this request and may even make it some day. A

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the firebug add-on for firefox (idk if there are other browsers addons)

Comment: I wasn't clear enough: I want it to aid positioning with drag-n-drop. Thanks for your answer though

Answer (score 0):

Use:

- **Webkit/Opera Web Inspector**
- **Or firebug**
- **Javascript: document editable could also help you**

For drag and Drop; Use a WYSYWIG editor like Dreamweaver or Muse.

Comment: Can I restrict Dreamweaver or Muse to not muck with anything other than CSS `left` and `top`? Normally I wouldn't touch these applications with a 10-foot pole..